# passing a variable into a templates parameter

Tags: azure-devops

I have a template which has a parameter 'enableVM1' of type boolean.

Simply, I want this parameter to be set by an expression. I want this expression to resolve at **runtime** since the data is retrieved by an earlier step.

```
  - stage: Build_Tenant_Refresh
    displayName: "Destroying Tenant VM"
    variables:
       vm1ActiveFlip: $[ not(eq(stageDependencies.Shutdown_Tenant.Setup.outputs['Identify_built_VM.vm1Active'],'True')) ] 
    jobs:
    - template: tenant-infrastructure-plan.yml
      parameters:
         enableVM1: <<ANY EXPRESSION WHICH I'D EXPECT TO RESOLVE TO A BOOL>>
```

When I press the run button on the pipeline I am immediately told that enableVM1s value is not a boolean.
This suggests that the a parameters are evaluated at parse/compile time rather than run time. Is this true?

I was intending for the expression to be: $[vm1ActiveFlip] (referencing the variable defined at the stage).

I tried lots of variants for the expression including:

$[eq('vm1ActiveFlip','True')]
$[eq('True','True')]

Is it possible to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1):

I tested `enableVM1: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'],'refs/heads/main')]` and reproduced your issue:

[image]

To solve this , you need to use compile-time expressions (`${{ <expression> }}`). This is because if you use runtime expression, then when you click the run button, the expression has not been parsed as a boolean value and is judged as a string.

In a compile-time expression (`${{ <expression> }}`), you have access to `parameters` and statically defined `variables`. In a runtime expression (`$[ <expression> ]`), you have access to more `variables` but no parameters.

This is stated in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops),please refer to it.

Update:

As workaround, using job output variables and introducing a dependsOn to the template. For details , please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks).

Comment: Yeah  this is what I suspected from the behaviour I described - as such I worked around this using job  output variables and introducing a dependsOn to the template

Comment: Thanks for sharing your workaround, I added this to the answer.